# need to calculate max_connection

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to calculate max_connections. I already have a formula for it from this forum only which is

```
    max_connections = (Available RAM - Global Buffers) / Thread Buffers
```

I am not sure with the authenticity of this formula. Is there any other way around to cross check the value which I am getting from this formula and confirm on the max_connection value?

Comment: Show us the actual numbers from your system. What is your reference (link).